# Is there any API to display raw YUV video frames using android Surface?

Tags: android, surfaceview, yuv

I have a raw video file of `YUV 420` format and I want to read frame-by-frame and display the video on android device. I am not capturing any video frames using camera.

**Question:** Is there any API using Surface, `SurfaceView` so as to display the `YUV 420` raw video without any encoding and decoding processes?